# How can I convert a .amr file to a .mp3

Tags: mp3, mp3-player, amr

My phone records in .amr and my mp3 player can't play them, what's the simplest way to convert them?

Phone is Nokia C3-10 and mp3 player is an iPod classic, but I can easily get files off and on those two, I just need a nice simple bit of software to convert in between.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either a dedicated media converter program (like [this one](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php)), or a general purpose audio editor like [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

If you go for Audacity, make sure to also get the [LAME encoder](http://manual.audacityteam.org/help/manual/man/faq_installation_and_plug_ins.html#lame) (to be able to export to MP3 format) and the [FFmpeg library](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=FAQ:Installation_and_Plug-Ins#installffmpeg) (to be able to read AMR files).

Answer (score 1):

I'll recommend you the [Freemake audio converter](http://www.freemake.com/en/offline/offline_all/). Its completely free and supported many format.

[image]

Comment: This was a quick and easy way to do this several years later.  The interface is different now but it works.